# How can I export specific data into different pages in .PDF format?

Tags: export, output-formatting, formatting, grid-layouts, pdf-format

I have made various `Grid`-s and arranged them column-wise in another `Grid`.

All `Grids` are working fine and I exported that final `Grid` into PDF format.

The entire `Grid` appeared in a single page after exporting, but I want to `Export` some `Grid`-s to one page and remaining ``Grid`-s to another page.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
grid1 = Grid[{{Style["Life Alerts", Bold, 20], SpanFromLeft, 
 SpanFromLeft}, {Style["Alert", Bold, 15], Style["<>", Bold, 15], 
 Style["%Life", Bold, 15], 
 Style["OnDay", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L1", Bold, 15], 
 Style["<", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
 Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L2", Bold, 15], 
 Style[">", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
 Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L3", Bold, 15], 
 Style[">", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
 Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}}, Alignment -> {{Left}, Center}, 
  Background -> {None, {Yellow}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[4], Black], Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
    Dividers -> {{}, {True, True, True}}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  (*Exporting code*)
  Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave",".Pdf"], (Grid[{{grid1}, {grid1}}])]
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you may want something like this:

```
grid1 = 
  Grid[{{Style["Life Alerts", Bold, 20], SpanFromLeft, 
     SpanFromLeft}, {Style["Alert", Bold, 15], Style["<>", Bold, 15], 
     Style["%Life", Bold, 15], 
     Style["OnDay", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L1", Bold, 15], 
     Style["<", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
     Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L2", Bold, 15], 
     Style[">", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
     Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}, {Style["L3", Bold, 15], 
     Style[">", Bold, 15], Style["90", Bold, 15], 
     Style["0.35", Bold, 15]}}, Alignment -> {{Left}, Center}, 
   Background -> {None, {Yellow}}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[4], Black], Spacings -> {1, 1}, 
   Dividers -> {{}, {True, True, True}}];

With[{
  listOfGrids = {grid1, grid1}
  },
 Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", ".Pdf"], 
  CreateDocument[
   Riffle[listOfGrids, Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]],
    Visible -> False]]
 ]
```

The export method is the same as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13251/245).

**Edit**

In response to the comment, it looks like you're encountering some of the ugly formatting problems that are caused by the incompatible mixture of different coordinate systems used by *Mathematica*. Since `Grid` is a formatting construct that adjusts itself to its environment, it's really hard to freeze the shape of a grid in place for further manipulation and in particular for `Export`.

Instead of worrying about the fragility of the lengths scales in `Grid`, I would suggest that you'll save a lot of time and effort by converting each grid in your problem to a graphics object before doing anything else with it. To do this in a way that prevents any changes in relative dimensions, I would do the following with your test grid:

First I define a helper function `toPDF` that converts any argument to `PDF` within the notebook, and apply it to `grid1` from above. Then we export the grid of grids, but only after making sure that all the components (which are all `grid` here, but are now `Graphics` objects) have the same size in pixels, which I call `itemWidth`:

```
toPDF[x_] := 
 First[ImportString[ExportString[Magnify[x, .8], "PDF"], "PDF"]]

grid1 = toPDF[grid1];

With[{
  listOfGrids = {Grid[{{grid1, grid1, grid1, grid1}, {grid1, grid1, 
       grid1, grid1}, {grid1, grid1, grid1, grid1}, {grid1, grid1, 
       grid1, grid1}}], grid1},
  itemWidth = 90
  },
 Export["grids.Pdf",
  CreateDocument[
   Riffle[
    listOfGrids /. Graphics[x__] :> Show[
       Graphics[x],
       ImageSize -> itemWidth
       ],
    Cell["", "PageBreak", PageBreakBelow -> True]], Visible -> False]
  ]
 ]
```

Now the result of the export is a `PDF` file `grid.pdf` with two pages where all component grids are exactly the same size. I chose `itemWidth = 90` by hand so that it ends up small enough to allow four grids side by side on the output page, assuming letter size paper. You have to change that length scale depending on your needs.

The `itemWidth` is set by a replacement rule in which I look for `Graphics` objects and `Show` them with the desired size. Instead of this global replacement rule, you could also fine-tune the width of different component tables directly at the time when you define them, e.g., by setting

```
grid2 = Show[toPDF[grid2], ImageSize -> 100];
```

etc. Then you can leave out the replacement `/. Graphics[x__] :> Show[Graphics[x],ImageSize -> itemWidth]` above.

This is of course a less than optimal solution because I have to convert all component grids to graphics using `toPDF`. But that's just my standard response to problems with changing relative lengths (or fonts). It's just simpler than trying adjust a myriad of other lengths in the `Grid`s to get the desired result in the final export, because I find it almost impossible to predict how `Export` changes the appearance of a `Grid` in general.

Comment: your code working fine...for testing,I wrote this code  `listOfGrids={Grid[{{grid1,grid1,grid1,grid1},{grid1,grid1,grid1,grid1},{grid1,grid1,grid1,grid1},{grid1,grid1,grid1,grid1}}],grid1}` instead of your code like `listOfGrids={grid1,grid1}`.it's not working,actuvally `listOfGrids` have 2 elements but 5 pages are created after `Exporting`.how can I solve this?