# How to Export PDF with "Pages" "Rules"?

Tags: export, pdf-format

There is an `Export` syntax that lets you specify the elements being exported.  This appears to be ignored by `"PDF"`.

```
plots = Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> Large] & /@ {Sin, Cos, Tan};
```

To print each of `plots` to a PDF page the syntax is

```
SetDirectory[$UserDocumentsDirectory];
Export["plots.pdf", {"Pages" -> plots}, "Rules", "AllowRasterization" -> False]
ResetDirectory[];
```

However, the resulting PDF places the list (with curly braces) on one page of the PDF.

[image]

Any ideas how to get this to work?  Mind you this is in version 10.4 on Win 7 Ent as version 11.1.0 always crashes if I try to Export PDF even after reinstalling.

---

**Update**: WRI has responded and said that `"PDF"` `"Pages"` `Export` is not currently supported.  A similar workaround of creating a notebook with page break cells was provided.

Comment: "Pages" is an option for `Import`, non for `Export` 
You should look for printing environment styling If you wish to set the margins, paper size, etc for output document.

Comment: @Rom38 Look at the documentation for `"XLSX"` in the Elements section and notice how the `"Sheets"` element is documented. You can `Export` `"Sheets"` for Excel files.  In `"PDF"` `"Pages"` is documented the same as `"Sheets"` in `"XLSX"`.  Therefore, it stands to reason that you should be able to `Export` `"Pages"`.

Comment: logic is absent sometimes in Wolfram documentation.

Comment: Related: [(17008)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17008/280), [(13251)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13251/280).

Comment: @user6014 Export of `"Sheets"` is not undocumented. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 17):

You need something like this:

```
nb = CreateDocument[
   ExpressionCell[#, PageBreakBelow -> True] & /@ plots];
Export["plots.pdf", nb]
```

Therefore, you first create a structured document with page-breaks and then export (print) it to pdf.

Comment: This is a good workaround. (+1)

Comment: Is there any way to break cells too?

Comment: @H.R., I guess you should initially create cells with desired size (satisfying the good alignment regarding to current paper size)

Comment: Yeah, but that takes too much time for a long code. :)

Answer (score 7):

Turn off the popping up of the NB:

```
nb = CreateDocument[
   ExpressionCell[#, PageBreakBelow -> True] & /@ plots, Visible -> False];
Export["plots.pdf", nb]
```

After playing around a little bit it is clear that everything is already
-magically- built inside `CreateDocument` (*Mathematica* 10.3). Just activate the right Options:

```
nb = CreateDocument[plots, PageBreakBelow -> True, Visible -> False];
Export["plots.pdf", nb]
```

Comment: (+1) Nice discovery of `PageBreakBelow` being supported by `CreateDocument`! It looks like we can pass in the same way any other `Cell` option too.

Comment: e.g. TextAlignment -> Center is working.
Also tried to pass a List with individual ailgnmnet for pages
TextAlignment -> {Left,Left,Center,Right,...}
this unfortunately does not work