# How to export arbitrary number of plots to separate pages of a PDF file?

Tags: export

I have 8 plot, just for sample data

```
p1 = Plot[x, {x, 1, 5}];
p2 = Plot[x^2, {x, 1, 5}];
p3 = Plot[x^3, {x, 1, 5}];
p4 = Plot[x^4, {x, 1, 5}];
p5 = Plot[x^5, {x, 1, 5}];
p6 = Plot[x^6, {x, 1, 5}];
p7 = Plot[x^7, {x, 1, 5}];
p8 = Plot[x^8, {x, 1, 5}];
```

which I want to export in PDF as 4 plots in each page. So I tried

```
g1=GraphicsGrid[{{p1, p2}, {p3, p4}}]; 
g2=GraphicsGrid[{{p5, p6}, {p7, p8}}];
Export["plot.pdf", {g1, g2}]
```

where p's are my plots. However this code produces a PDF file as all plots are in a single page. I searched Mathematica SE and just found

```
nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[#, PageBreakBelow -> True] & /@ g1];
Export["plots.pdf", nb]
```

but this didn't work or maybe I didn't know how to use it. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying answer provided by [`Rom38`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146134/9362)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

plts = Plot[x^#, {x, 1, 5}] & /@ Range[8];

nb = CreateDocument[
   ExpressionCell[#, PageBreakBelow -> True] & /@ (GraphicsGrid /@ 
      ArrayReshape[plts, {2, 2, 2}])];

Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/plots.pdf", nb]

(* "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/plots.pdf" *)
```

**EDIT:** If instead of 2 by 2 arrays you want 4 by 1 arrays

```
plts = Plot[x^#, {x, 1, 5},
     PlotLabel -> StringForm["n = ``", #]] & /@ Range[8];

nb = CreateDocument[
   ExpressionCell[#, 
      PageBreakBelow -> True] & /@ (GraphicsGrid[#, ImageSize -> 360] & /@ 
      ArrayReshape[plts, {2, 4, 1}])];

Export["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/plots.pdf", nb, ImageSize -> 500]

(* "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/plots.pdf" *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However there is a tiny problem: 4 plots have not been fitted to the size of page and just occupied the upper half of the page, how can I resize them best fitted in a page or use landscape style for PDF file to best fit?

Comment: @Wisdom A "tiny" problem... AFAIK, up to now, there is no solution without using third-party software like Poppler. You can export every page as a separate PDF file, and then combine them using `pdfunite` (a part of [Poppler utilities](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows)).